# ASP .NET Web API How to return error on unsupported media type

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, mediatypeformatter

My Web API controller deals with some third party class in one of its methods

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult CreateJob([FromBody] ThirdPartyCustomType item)
{
  //Something useful done here
}
```

It is parsed using custom media type formatter and has it's own media type "application/json+customType".

The problem is that when parameter content type is specified incorrectly(for example "application/json"). Web API uses another formatter to parse request body and then when it tries to create instance of ThirdPartyCustomType it fails some internal validation and throws NullReferenceException.

How can I tell Web API not to try and parse request body when content type is wrong?

**EDIT:** As guys in comments suggested I created a middleware class, now the thing is that all requests are getting caught there and I need this validation to work only for one. I think that I can check Request.Path in my middleware and act only if it corresponds to my request but that does not seems like good solution.

**Another edit** Finally it looks like this:

```
public class ContentTypeCheckMiddleWare : OwinMiddleware
{
    public ContentTypeCheckMiddleWare(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
    {
    }

    public async override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Path.Value.EndsWith("myRouteSuffix") && context.Request.Method == "POST")
        {
            var contentType = context.Request.ContentType;

            if (contentType != "application/json+customType")
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 416;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(
                    "Invalid content type.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await Next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: You are going to have to write some custom middleware to handle the request before it hits the controller.

Comment: you can get the request headers and check it.

Comment: You can use Owin middlewares to handle the request before that request will hit to controller action. Just derive from OwinMiddleware class and implement his abstract method.

Comment: What exactly is your question now? It seems you've fixed it?

Answer (score 2):

When the return type is IHttpActionResult you can use built in response types such as Ok(), BadRequest() or NotFound() and for the rest of the status codes you can use StatusCode(HttpStatusCode statuscode) method.

```
return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
```